# Grafana Loki LogQL bar gauge order by total

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I am using Grafana and Loki to analyze logs from my application, and have used the Bar Gauge in a few places already.

This is my query:

```
sum(count_over_time({namespace=~"$namespace", job=~"$namespace-logs"} 
|= "KPIExecuted" [$__interval])) by (namespace)
```

And I get:

[image]

I was wondering whether I can sort the results based on the metric result? Or if there is an alternative I could use to achieve a similar outcome?

Thanks.

Comment: ever found out?

Comment: When I have an answer I will add it in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit different problem, but I think it might be helpful for somebody searching how to sort bars in bar chart.
I have a table with queries from users and I wanted to find the most active users.
Right solution:

```
SELECT
  count(user_id) as "Количество запросов",
  CONCAT("vk.com/id", user_id)  as "Пользователь"
FROM 
  strawberry.generated_data
WHERE 
  unix_date>$since 
GROUP BY 
  user_id 
ORDER BY
  count(user_id) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

My problem was that i was selecting time and bars so mixed

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing the same thing as me, the problem was you had a reduced Total each in a different table.

Instead you need to reduce different tables (ie. labels) into a single table with a "Series to Rows" reducer and sort with the "Total" field

[image: Transformation]

Answer (score -2):

You can use a Sort Transform to do this.

Next to the `Query Tab` is a `Transform Tab`. Click that and choose `Sort By`. You will most likely sort by `Value #A`

Documentation is here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/types-options/#sort-by

Comment: It is not working :(

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works when the labels are the same value. But when you have different labels there, you can't sort them by the bar values.